# Using smart pointers in a struct or class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I've written a function that loads the bytes off a file and returns a FileData struct that contains the byte buffer and the length of the buffer.

I want the buffer to be deleted as soon as it's consumed and thrown out of scope.

I'm having trouble getting it to compile due to various casting errors. Also, I'm not sure whether the buffer is being moved correctly rather than copied. I don't mind the FileData struct itself being copied, since it's maybe 16 bytes at most.

In general, how do you use smart pointers as class/struct fields? Is that even something you'd do?

This is a bit of a nebulous question, I know, but since I'm having some conceptual difficulties with smart pointers in general, I'm hoping that this example will help me in the right direction.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
struct FileData
{
    unique_ptr<char[]> buf;
    unsigned int len;
};

FileData LoadFile(string filename)
{
    ifstream str;
    str.open(filename, ios::binary);

    str.seekg(0, ios::end);
    auto len = str.tellg();
    str.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    char* buf = new char[len];

    str.read(buf, len);
    str.close();

    FileData d = { unique_ptr<char[]>(buf), len };

    return d;
}
```

**Edit:** Since some people are curious about the error message that I get with this current code, here it is:

```
error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
```

Comment: Your problem is that you don't give any specific details about the error messages at all. How on earth can we possibly identify them else?

Comment: @DeadMG I assumed it'd be clear that there are problems with the code, since I did point out that I'm not sure this is the correct way to go about using smart pointers and move semantics. I'd like the code to do more than compile; I'd like it to be correct and idiomatic. Nonetheless, I've updated the question with the error message.

Comment: The error you are getting is because you were trying to copy a unique_ptr, you have to use std::move. You could have used a shared_ptr and declared your own deallocator, but the vector solution is much cleaner.

Comment: @pstrjds I figured as much. I get a different error when I do that, though (and that's why I didn't want to bother sharing the error message): `error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'`

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka - The vector solution is much cleaner anyway, and if the compiler you are using supports the C++11 move constructors then it is no more expensive than copying the struct around.

Comment: @pstrjds What would I do if something like `vector` weren't available, hypothetically speaking?

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka - In that case I would add a method to the struct to allow me to assign the unique_ptr, construct it outside the method and pass it as a non-const reference to the LoadFile call, then you could set the pointer in the call (see Remy's answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is fine, except for one little detail:

```
struct FileData
{
    unique_ptr<char[]> buf;
    <del>unsigned int</del> <ins>streamoff</ins> len;
};
```

The reason it doesn't compile for you is that your compiler does not yet implement the automatic generation of the special move members.  In a fully C++11 conforming compiler your `FileData` would behave as if:

```
struct FileData
{
    unique_ptr<char[]> buf;
    streamoff len;

    FileData(FileData&&) = default;
    FileData& operator=(FileData&&) = default;
    FileData(const FileData&) = delete;
    FileData& operator=(const FileData&) = delete;
    ~FileData() = default;
};
```

The defaulted move constructor simply move constructs each member (and similarly for the defaulted move assignment).

When returning `d` from `LoadFile`, there is an implicit move that takes place which will bind to the implicitly defaulted move constructor.

Use of `vector<char>` or `string` as others have suggested will also work.  But there is nothing wrong with your code as far as C++11 is concerned.

Oh, I might tweak it like so:  I like to get my resources owned as quickly as possible:

```
FileData LoadFile(string filename)
{
    ifstream str;
    str.open(filename, ios::binary);

    str.seekg(0, ios::end);
    auto len = str.tellg();
    str.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    FileData d = {unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[len]), len};

    str.read(d.buf.get(), d.len);
    str.close();

    return d;
}
```

If you need to explicitly define the `FileData` move members, it should look like:

```
struct FileData
{
    unique_ptr<char[]> buf;
    streamoff len;

    FileData(FileData&& f)
        : buf(std::move(f.buf)),
          len(f.len)
        {
            f.len = 0;
        }

    FileData& operator=(FileData&& f)
    {
        buf = std::move(f.buf);
        len = f.len;
        f.len = 0;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Oh, which brings me to another point.  The defaulted move members are not **exactly** correct since they don't set `len` to 0 in the source.  It depends on your documentation if this is a bug or not.  `~FileData()` doesn't require `len` to reflect the length of the buffer.  But other clients might.  If you define a moved-from `FileData` as not having a reliable `len`, then the defaulted move members are fine, else they aren't.

Comment: `FileData(FileData&&) = default;` -- is that a shorthand syntax that works on some compilers? When I try to create a move constructor myself explicitly, it complains that `operator=` is inaccessible. Hmm... (VC++11, by the way)

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka:  Yes, the `= default` syntax is a way to explicitly request what in C++98/03 you would refer to as the implicitly generated special member.  Works for the default ctor, copy ctor, copy assignment, move ctor, move assignment and dtor.  But it may not be implemented for you yet (I'm not familiar with VC++11).  These features were standardized late in the game so it is understandable that your compiler may not have them yet. The "= delete" syntax is roughly equivalent to declaring it private and not defining it.  I'm not sure what is going on with your explicit move ctor.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a `std::vector` instead of a `std:::unique_ptr<char[]>`, if you don't mind the `std::vector` being copied when you return the `FileData`:

```
struct FileData 
{ 
    vector<char> buf; 
}; 

FileData LoadFile(string filename) 
{ 
    ifstream str; 
    str.open(filename, ios::binary); 

    str.seekg(0, ios::end); 
    auto len = str.tellg(); 
    str.seekg(0, ios::beg); 

    FileData d; 
    d.buf.resize(len); 

    str.read(&(d.buf)[0], len); 
    str.close(); 

    return d; 
}
```

Alternatively, to avoid the copy, the caller can pass in a `FileData` as a function parameter instead of a return value:

```
struct FileData 
{ 
    vector<char> buf; 
}; 

void LoadFile(string filename, FileData &data) 
{ 
    ifstream str; 
    str.open(filename, ios::binary); 

    str.seekg(0, ios::end); 
    auto len = str.tellg(); 
    str.seekg(0, ios::beg); 

    data.buf.resize(len); 

    str.read(&(data.buf)[0], len); 
    str.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this lead to the file data "array" itself being copied, or does vector implement the C++11 move semantics? Not trying to be argumentative, just curious.

Comment: In that case I wouldn't even need the FileData struct, so that answers half of my question. Thanks. I take it the performance isn't too bad with resizing a vector?

Comment: @Rei: It won't resize in the given example. Because it's initially empty, it's more like "size" :P and it's no slower than allocating the memory yourself.

Comment: Answered my own curiosity - http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html